# Is a reconfiguration of running Ingress in Kubernetes possible without downtime?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

We are currently facing the following situation:

```
Ingress1_legacy: service.domain.com
  / >> service_legacy

Ingress2_new: service_one.domain.com, service_two.domain.com
  /one >> service_new_one
  /two >> service_new_two
```

Our plan is to seamlessly redirect service.domain.com to service_new_one. The idea was now to edit Ingress1 to point to service_new_one like this:

```
Ingress1_legacy (updated): service.domain.com
  / >> service_new_one
```

What we experience is, that as soon as we change the configuration of Ingress1_legacy, calls to service.domain.com result in 502. This situation persisted long enough for us to better roll back to the original configuration.

So is this a feasible strategy? Is our assumption right, that the changed configuration of the service-route in the Ingress should allow for a seamless, **immediate** migration to the other service? Or would a change of an Ingress configuration normally lead to some downtime of the loadbalancing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**: when you update the ingress resource there is a small  downtime due to the process needed both in the Google Cloud Platform and in the Kubernetes one.

I do not exclude that there are way to minimise or cancel the downtime, but if you simply update the ingress you will experience it.

---

**Small experiment**
We have the following ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /index.html
        backend:
          serviceName: httpd
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /apache
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```

And 4 service `nginx`, `nxing2`, `httpd` and `httpd2` ponting to 4 different deployment each of them on a different node.

Run:

```
kubectl run nginx2 --image=nginx
kubectl run nginx2 --image=nginx
kubectl run httpd --image=httpd:2.4
kubectl run httpd2 --image=httpd:2.4
```

and create:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: httpd
spec:
  selector:
    run: httpd2
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
---
kind: Service
[...]
```

We connect to http://ingress-ip/index.html and we visualise the classical "**It works!**"

As soon as you change the ingress to point `nginx2` and `httpd2`:

- ~ 1 minute continue to serve old service
- ~ 1 minute `/nginx` leads you to "`Error: Server Error`" and `/index.html` "`default backend - 404`"
- after 3 minutes finally we go back to a stable situation